# Bash script stops using variable with no reason

Tags: bash, awk, grep, scripting

I'm stuck on this script. I've defined a variable with a single cat of a temp file, and these are the following operations done by the script.

```
PROJECT=$(cat temp/project_name_final) ;

#Bifidobacterium contigs selection

grep "Bifidobacterium" ${PROJECT}_genera.txt | gawk '{print $2}' > temp/${PROJECT}_Bif_genera ;
gawk '{print $3}' ${PROJECT}_species.txt > temp/${PROJECT}_Bif_species ;
grep -v -f temp/${PROJECT}_Bif_species temp/${PROJECT}_Bif_genera > temp/${PROJECT}_selected_Bif ;
```

The first grep works fine, the awk one too. Variable is used well into the given filename. The last grep seems to work bad, and the generated file is named "_selected_Bif" , so the variable isn't used as before. I'm tryin to find a way to explain why I get this trouble.

TL;DR 
None of the used file are empty. The expected file, named "${PROJECT}_selected_Bif" also could not be empty, if grep works as expected.

Comment: Run the script with `bash -x` to see what commands are actually run.

Comment: Already done. grep and gawk work properly. They use the variable because output files, which are not empty, are named correctly.

Comment: Please put `echo PROJECT=\""$PROJECT"\"` before each command.

Comment: Done. Project names are prompted well also before the last grep command.

Comment: Just to make sure you're looking in the right place... Are you looking in the temp directory, and you can't find the last output file there?

Comment: My problem is that the last output file has got a wrong filename. Even if it is an empty file, it **must** have got the variable into its filename.

Comment: To clarify, you are looking in the temp directory, not in the current directory?

Comment: Check for typo in variable name...

Comment: side note: the style guide for Unix says that shell variables should be lowercase, unless exported, in which case they should be all capitals.

Comment: Underneath your definition of `PROJECT` please could you humour me and add the output of running `echo ">$PROJECT<"`.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't see why the `PROJECT` variable is not getting expanded properly on you last line of code (unless you're looking in the wrong place for the generated file), but I do see that you don't properly double quote your variable expansions.  Not double quoting these would cause issues as soon as `$PROJECT` contained spaces or newlines, or any other character that is special to the shell.

You are also jumping through a lot of hoops for something that could be done with a single `awk` program:

```
proj=$(<temp/project_name_final)

awk 'NR==FNR { species[$3]; next } /Bifidobacterium/ && !($2 in species) { print $2 }' \
    "${proj}_species.txt" "${proj}_genera.txt" >"temp/${proj}_selected_Bif"
```

This `awk` program reads the two files `${proj}_species.txt` and `${proj}_genera.txt`.  While reading the first file, its third column is used to create a key in the associative array or hash `species`.  When we then start reading the second file, we are only interested in lines that contain the string `Bifidobacterium` and whose second column is not a key in the `species` hash.  For those lines, we output the second column.

All output goes to `temp/${proj}_selected_Bif`.

Note the double quoting of all expansions of the `proj` variable.  I used a lower-cased variable name since upper-cased variables are reserved for system and shell environment variables.

See also

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

Comment: Thanks for the awk solution, I'm still a beginner with bash. What I actually don't understand is why while replacing the last grep command, without using any other trick like double quotes, filename is printed correctly. What I've seen till now is that redirection of stdout into a file always work, also with empty stdout.

Comment: @Shred Yes, any redirection with `>` creates the output file (or empties it if it exists) before the command is even started (if the output file is writable at all).

Answer (score 1):

Your initial file contains a line that ends with CR/LF. The CR is carried through as part of the `$PROJECT` variable, and as CR is a valid character in a filename, all the intermediate steps work correctly. (But the filenames are "wrong".)

The last output is also correct, but the CR in the filename is interpreted to force the cursor back to the beginning of the line, so all you see is `_selected_Bif`.

You can prove this by stripping the CR as you read the file contents.

Comment: ...and on this basis the question is a duplicate. But I can't find it.

Comment: False. By changing the last grep instruction, filename is printed correctly.

Comment: And I don't understand why just the last redirection of stdout will print the "wrong" filename, if there's a CR/LF ending line. (false, I've double checked now).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved. 
Trouble here is that grep without other instruction isn't able to handle lines without sorting them. So the output file will be empty, and, don't know why, grep create this empty file but with a wrong filename. (anyone knows why?)

So instead of

```
$ grep -v -f
```

I've used

```
$ grep -F -x -v -f
```

Comment: `grep` doesn't care if the lines are sorted; if you can show evidence of different behavior, that'd be good for a separate question (new questions don't go in Answers)

Comment: `grep` does not create a file. When you use redirection, the shell creates the file. So the file name cannot possibly have anything to do with the options you pass to `grep`. If editing the file fixed it, maybe there was a non-ASCII character or a control character somewhere and you removed it without noticing. But without seeing your exact source, that's just speculation.